# Selenium c#: What is the best way to get a new instance of a RemoteWebElement without using the autoID / Class, Instance etc?

Tags: c#, selenium

How can I refresh my RemoteWebElements in c# / selenium?

I have 2 Methods...

```
    public static bool ClickMe_Method_1(WindowsDriver<RemoteWebElement> driver, RemoteWebElement button_ToClick)
    {
        //Click
        button_ToClick.Click();

        //Assert the click worked and the button is now not Enabled
        Assert.IsFalse(button_ToClick.Enabled);//This Assert will never work because button_ToClick variable is now out of date and needs to be refreshed in this code somehow.
        return button_ToClick.Enabled;
    }

    public static bool ClickMe_Method_2(WindowsDriver<RemoteWebElement> driver, RemoteWebElement button_ToClick, string automationID)
    {
        //Click
        button_ToClick.Click();

        //This line refreshes the button_ToClick
        //BUT is there a way to do this without passing the automationID? 
        //This is a simple example and will only work where I want to click        
        //the first or only instance of a button with this automation ID so 
        //this solution is not very scalable.
        button_ToClick = driver.FindElementByAccessibilityID(automationID);

        //Assert the click worked and the button is now not Enabled
        Assert.IsFalse(button_ToClick.Enabled);
        return button_ToClick.Enabled;
    }
```

In the above code, method1 will always fail because the "button_ToClick" has not been updated in my test solution after it was clicked. So if the click works and the button_ToClick Enabled becomes false, my code will not know Enable has now become = false.

**My question is this**: Do I have to pass in the automation ID and use a FindElement approach to find the latest (as in method 2) OR is there a way I can ask selenium to update the button_ToClick that I have.

**NB**: The RemoteWeElement (button_ToClick in my case) does not have the auto ID. Unless I am missing something, there isn't a way to get it at this stage inside my method without passing the auto ID in separately.

**Background**: The real reason I am asking this question is because the autoID alone sometimes is not enough. I might be testing a table of rows where each row has a button. Let's say the calling method had done some clever work and I know I want to click the 4th button (index = 3 as count is from zero). In this case I would need a 3rd method (after my 2 methods above) and it would have to know my auto ID AND the instance. This is a pain, less tidy and I will now be introducing testers to this solution and I want the easiest, most readable code.

Comment: If anyone knows the answer but it's not in c#, feel free to post an answer and I can convert it to c#. Also if you have a WebAppDriver solution, I think the important thing this has in common with that is the 'RemoteWebElement'. BTW, the System Under Test is a windows WPF application. A bit like web GUI testing in many ways.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the relevant portion of HTML?

Comment: Please also provide the C# code used to call these two methods. Some context of how they are used might help.

Comment: Are you getting a StaleElementException?

Comment: Thanks Greg, I will be working tomorrow so I'll add more detail then. For now, my system under test is WPF so the markup language is XAML as opposed to HTML. Do you still want to see it? I don't normally look at XAML (even though I can write it). I just use inspect.exe.

Comment: There is no exception, the only problem is that if I click the button, all of it's attributes (Enabled etc) will be slightly old and out of date. In my head, I want to write a line of code like this but this isn't acceptable selenium...   button_ToClick .Refresh();